# How to efficiently count the number of spatial points within a certain distance around raster cells in R?

Tags: r, vector, distance, spatial, raster

I would like to count the number of spatial points (of a `SpatialPointsDataFrame` object) within a certain distance to every cell of a `RasterLayer` in R. The resulting value should replace the original value of that particular raster cell. 
Here is a reproducible example:

```
# load library
library(raster)

# generate raster
ras <- raster(nrow=18, ncol=36)
values(ras) <- NA

# create SpatialPointsDataFrame
x <- c(-160,-155,-153,-150, 30, -45, -44, -42, -40, 100, 110, 130)
y <- c(-75,-73,-71,-60, 0, 30, 35, 40, 41, 10, -10, 60)
z <- c(seq(1, 12, 1))
df <- data.frame(x,y,z)
spdf <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords=df[,c(1,2)],
                               data=as.data.frame(df[,3]), 
                               proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))
# visualize
plot(ras)
plot(spdf, add=T)

# loop over all raster cells
for(r in 1:nrow(ras)){
  for(c in 1:ncol(ras)){
    # duplicate raster for subsequent modification
    ras_x <- ras
    # define cell for which to count the number of surrounding points
    ras_x[r,c] <- nrow(spdf) # some value that is impossible to be true, this is only a temporary placeholder
    ras_x[ras_x != nrow(spdf)] <- NA
    # convert raster cell to spatial point
    spatial_point <- rasterToPoints(ras_x, spatial=T)
    # calculate distance around raster cell
    ras_dist <- distanceFromPoints(ras_x, spatial_point)
    ras_dist <- ras_dist / 1000000 # scale values
    # define circular zone by setting distance threshold (raster only with values 1 or NA)
    ras_dist[ras_dist > 2] <- NA
    ras_dist[ras_dist <= 2] <- 1

    # create empty vector to count number of spatial points located within zone around the particular raster cell
    empty_vec <- c()
    # loop to check which value every point of SpatialPointsDataFrame corresponds to 
    for (i in 1:nrow(spdf)){
      point <- extract(ras_dist, spdf[i,])
      empty_vec[i] <- point
    }
    # sum of resulting vector is the number of points within surrounding zone around predefined raster cell
    val <- sum(na.omit(empty_vec))
    val
    ras[r,c] <- val

    # print for progress monitoring
    print(paste0("sum of points within radius around cell row ", r, " and column ", c, " is ", val))
    print(paste0("finished ", r, " out of ", nrow(ras)))
    print(paste0("finished ", c, " out of ", ncol(ras)))
    # both plots are just for visualization and progress monitoring
    plot(ras)
    plot(spdf, add=T)
  }
}

plot(ras)
plot(spdf, add=T)
```

[image]

The resulting raster is exactly what I want but my way of checking the underlying raster values for each point of the `SpatialPointsDataFrame` seems inefficient. My real data consists of a `RasterLayer` with 2160, 4320, 9331200 (nrow, ncol, ncell) and a `SpatialPointsDataFrame` with 2664 features.
Is there a way to generate the raster of simply counting how many points are located within a certain distance around every raster cell more efficiently?

Answer (score 2):

If you can work with projected coordinates this can be done fairly easily with the spatstat package.
This requires you to project your points (and grid) with e.g. `sf::st_transform()` and will not work
on a global scale.

Load spatstat and make 2000 random points to test against:

```r
library(spatstat)
W <- square(1)
set.seed(42)
Y <- runifpoint(2000) # Random points in the unit square
plot(Y, main = "Random points in unit square")
```

[image]

Make 3000x3000 grid of points (9 million points):

```r
xy <- gridcenters(W, 3000, 3000) # Grid of points in the unit square
X <- ppp(xy$x, xy$y, window = W, check = FALSE, checkdup = FALSE)
```

For each of the 9 million grid points count the number of other points within
radius 0.01 (timed on my resonably fast laptop with 16GB RAM):

```r
system.time(counts <- crosspaircounts(X, Y, r = .01))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   1.700   0.228   1.928
```

Convert to spatstat’s `im`-format (raster type format – can be converted with maptools) and plot:

```r
rslt <- as.im(data.frame(x = xy$x, y = xy$y, counts))
plot(rslt, main = "Point counts in raster cells")
```

[image]

The points overlayed on the counts shows that we have done the right thing:

```r
plot(rslt, main = "Point counts in raster cells")
plot(Y, add = TRUE, col = rgb(1,1,1,.7), pch = 3)
```

[image]

I’m sure you can also do something elegant and fast with `raster`, but I’m not the right one to ask there.